# Don't display GA4 code to Google Lighthouse and Google PageSpeed

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, pagespeed, google-analytics-4

Google Analytics code removes one score from achieving a 100/100 score on PageSpeed Insights.

The solution with the Universal Analytics (UA) was to not show it to the google crawlers via:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Speed Insights") == -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome-Lighthouse") == -1) {
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-<PUT YOUR GOOGLE ANALYTICS ID HERE>', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
}
```

Worked fine.

But as of today, UA is being deprecated and everyone needs to upgrade to Google Analytics 4 (GA4).

**How can we use this code for GA4**? So we don't display it to the appropriate Google crawlers.

Comment: All that is doing is fooling you and the business into thinking your PSI score is better than it really is. I suggest you train people into focusing less on those scores and more on user experience.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so what the question misses is the reason why you'd want to fake your page speed metrics. There are two common reasons for it:

1. You know you need GA as is and there's nothing to optimize, so you want to get rid of it from your report and concentrate on optimizing other things. It's quite a weak reason. You want to always see the full picture. Because scripts can conflict and removing them from your view is dangerous.
2. A junior SEO expert believing lighthouse info is shared with other Google products to influence ranking. I know it sounds ridiculous, but there are a lot of technically challenged SEOs who believe it helps. It doesn't. To make it work, one would have to do the exceptions for google's search indexing crawlers rather than speed bots, but now that is called cloaking, which is in the realm of black SEO and it is potentially punishable.

In general, what your script does is the most basic GA UA tracking. With this level of tracking, you don't even need to change your code. You can ask GA4 to use UA's tracker and you will start seeing your data in a GA4 property completely seamlessly. You can do it in your GA UA by going to Admin -> GA4 Setup Assistant

Alternatively, you can surely do exactly what you ask for though there's no real need given how simple your usage of GA is. Nevertheless, here is your code for GA4:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Speed Insights") == -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome-Lighthouse") == -1) {
  (function (s, o, g) {
    let a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
  })(document, 'script', 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-<YOUR GA DATA STREAM MEASUREMENT ID HERE>');

  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', '<YOUR GA DATA STREAM MEASUREMENT ID HERE TOO>');
}
```

Tested it on an example page and it works as intended. Note that you need to insert your GA4 data stream measurement id in two places there. I preserved the original approach here, just cut out extras mostly. GA UA used to use a much more powerful library. GA4 is quite a downgrade in comparison.